# How to upload self signed SSL certificate to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was following the tutorial here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html

But I'm stuck at this step:

```
PROMPT>aws iam upload-server-certificate --server-certificate-name certificate_object_name --certificate-body file://public_key_certificate_file --private-key file://privatekey.pem --certificate-chain file://certificate_chain_file
```

What exactly should I fill for `certificate_object_name`, `public_key_certificate_file` and `certificate_chain_file`?

Comment: Nope. Dropped Elastic Beanstalk and used EC2 instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/27216313/3107308

Answer (score 1):

certificate_object_name is a name of your choosing to identify it --  you'll end up selecting/specifying it during a later step when you update the elastic--beanstalk load balancer settings  (per the AWS instructions you were following:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html     Step 3)

public_key_certificate_file is the name of the public key file you should have either (a) received from your certification authority (whic is outside the scope of their instruction), or, (b) the self-signed public certificate that you generated in step 2 (under the heading "To generate a self-signed certificate") --  (note that self-signed certificates are really more appropriate for dev environments, and for production you'll want to research getting a 3rd-party-signed certificate).

certificate_chain_file -  I believe this also comes from the 3rd-party signing authority, if you use them -- and is optional if you are using a self-signed certificate for development purposes