# Issues trying to configure SSL on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Webserver (single instance) PHP

Tags: php, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am in the process of migrating a website for a client to AWS. I have everything configured and working except that the client would like to be able to accept payments on there website. I followed several guides on how to get SSL working using elastic beanstalk. Currently I have it set up to use a source bundle and I created a config file in the .ebextensions file that looks like this:

```
Resources:
 sslSecurityGroupIngress:
   Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
   Properties:
    GroupName: {Ref : AWSEBSecurityGroup}
    IpProtocol: tcp
    ToPort: 443
    FromPort: 443
    CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl : []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
         <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
         </Proxy>
         SSLEngine on
         SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
         SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
         SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"

         ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
         ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
         ProxyPreserveHost on

         LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
         ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
         TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
       </VirtualHost>

      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
         mode: "000400"
         owner: root
         group: root
         source: sourceHere

      /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
        mode: "000400"
        owner: root
        group: root
        source: sourceHere
```

where sourceHere is the link to the file in S3, I have also tried using content directly in place of source but the result is the same, the application launches without any errors but any attempts to connect to the IP address or provided URL just say that the page is unavailable. If i build the same zip file but leave out the config files it builds correctly. This is pretty much exactly what AWS has on there support page and in the documentation for Elastic Beanstalk so I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: Did you try to access your website with https? `https://<app_url>`

Comment: I tried it with the IP address and the provided app url. The only thing I didn't try was changing the actual DNS records but I didn't want to take the site down.

Comment: Did you look at the logs? Apache may not be starting because of a problem with the SSL certificate

Comment: I don't see the error logs in the place they are supposed to be according the config file there are other logs that are auto generated by elastic beanstalk but not the ones specified. Also the files are not located on the server as they are specified either.

Comment: no `/var/log/httpd/error_log`?

Comment: there is but it is empty, the size is 0 and there is nothing in it

Comment: it looks like a certificate error then. Can you check that `server.crt` and `server.key` are located in `/etc/pki/tls/certs/` and are formatted properly?

Comment: Yeah they didn't get uploaded, weird I will have to make sure I have the right stuff then. I tried both pasting in the certs using content and linking using source like I did before. Weird that there is no error or anything about that just flying blind

Comment: hmm I think I discovered why: in your config file `/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt` and `/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key` should be at the same level as `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`. You need to correct the indentation.

Comment: Hi @Gordnfreeman I have also posted similar question for a Single instance EBS here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500028/how-can-i-configure-ssl-for-my-elastic-beanstalk-single-instance. I am not sure how do I get the content of the Certificates that I should use in the configuration file. And Shall I use Server Certificate for this or Client Certificate for this. Can you please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem of indentation in your config file: `/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt` and `/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key` should be at the same level as `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`.

You should correct the indentation so you get:

```
files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
         <Proxy *>
           Order deny,allow
           Allow from all
         </Proxy>
         SSLEngine on
         SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
         SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
         SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"

         ProxyPass / http://localhost:80/ retry=0
         ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:80/
         ProxyPreserveHost on

         LogFormat "%h (%{X-Forwarded-For}i) %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
         ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
         TransferLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-access_log
       </VirtualHost>

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
     mode: "000400"
     owner: root
     group: root 
     source: sourceHere

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
     mode: "000400"
     owner: root
     group: root
     source: sourceHere
```

Comment: You were right! Thank you so much now I will not be making that mistake in the future!

Answer (score 8):

Instead of provisioning SSL via .ebextensions you should look at adding it via the Load Balancer under the Elastic Beanstalk Environment configuration >> Networking Tier >> Load Balancing.

[image]

The easiest way, other than using the CLI tools, is to create a EC2 load balancer and add the keys. Once you pass stage 2 (Select Certificate) then you can abort and the certificate will be save for Elastic Beanstalk usage.

1. Create Load Balancer
2. Add HTTPS

[image]

3. Add Private Key, Public Key Certificate, Certificate Chain.
4. Continue, then abort.
5. The SSL Certificate will now be available in your Elastic Beanstalk Environment.

[image]

Comment: This probably would have been much easier, I am not sure why it is not part of the wizard to create a Elastic Beanstalk environment. Also the web server it is configured as a Single Instance so I don't know if that changes the process at all but I am still pretty new to AWS. I will definitely try this out though!

Comment: This is the method to follow when you have a load balancer. This won't work for a Single Instance though. In the AWS documentation you have the 2 cases, with load balancer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html and without load balancer: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSL.SingleInstance.html

Comment: +1 for the networking configuration on Elastic Beanstalk to provide the ssl cert. Another easy way to add a ssl cert is to add a https listener under EC2->Load Balancers->Listeners

Comment: Yeah but how do you configure in this case the ProxyPass rules without modifying the config file?

Comment: much easier, but at the cost of 20 bucks/month

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use letsencrypt you can try this: Heres a way to install certs on single instance elastic beanstalk node servers: http://bluefletch.com/blog/domain-agnostic-letsencrypt-ssl-config-for-elastic-beanstalk-single-instances/

Basically an automated .ebextension to install certbot, get a cert, and link nginx to it.